# How to define a generic nested object in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to have a nested object in the detail for the activiy log. See the example. How do I define the schema in mongoose?

```
activity: {
    date: '1/1/2012' ,
    user: 'benbittly', 
    action: 'newIdea', 
    detail: {
        'title': 'how to nest'
        , 'url': '/path/to/idea'
    }

activity: {
    date: '1/2/2012' ,
    user: 'susyq', 
    action: 'editProfile', 
    detail: {
        'displayName': 'Susan Q'
        , 'profileImageSize': '32'
        , 'profileImage': '/path/to/image'
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the **Mixed** type, which allows you to store the arbitrary sub-objects in your example.

```
var Activity = new Schema({
    date : Date
  , user : String 
  , action : String
  , detail : Mixed
})
```

Comment: What about the `markModified` part that @RyanM is mentioning. Is that always required?

Answer (score 14):

To indicate an arbitrary object (i.e. "anything goes") in your schema you can use the `Mixed` type or simply `{}`.

```
var activity: new Schema({
    date: Date,
    user: String, 
    action: String, 
    detail: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    meta: {}  // equivalent to Schema.Types.Mixed

});
```

#### The catch

For the added flexibility there is a catch, however. When using `Mixed` (or `{}`), you will need to explicitly tell mongoose that you have made changes like so:

```
activity.detail.title = "title";
activity.markModified('detail');
activity.save();
```

#### Source

- [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed)